# Select statement with a condition on multiple entries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, view

Following is my table:

[image]

I want to create a view with the following conditions in a select statement:

If count(employee_id) > 1 then only the record having status = 'Current' is picked in the view.

I tried:

```
select employee_id
    , case when COUNT(employee_id) > 1 and statusval = 'Current' then 'Y' else 'N' end as val
from table1
group by employee_id
```

I hope someone can help me with this statement. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @DaleK, I have tried few case statements but doesn't work.

Comment: I think my approach of considering case expression for this query was not right.  I had following statement: select employee_id,
  case when COUNT(employee_id) >1 and statusval = 'Current'
  then 'Y' else 'N'
  end as val,
    from table1
 group by employee_id   & I was going to include only those records with val = 'Y'  in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to show you how your attempt could have looked. You were nearly there, you just needed to use the windowed version of `count` e.g.

```
with cte as (
    select Employee_Id, [Status]
        , case when count(*) over (partition by id) > 1 and [Status] = 'Current' then 1 else 0 end Val
    from Table1
)
select Employee_Id, [Status]
from cte
where Val = 1;
```

And this approach appears on the face of it to perform better than a join.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID INT, STATUS VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @T VALUES (1,'Current'),(2,'Historical'),(2,'Historical'),(2,'Current')

SELECT * FROM @T M
INNER JOIN (SELECT ID FROM @T
            GROUP BY ID
            HAVING COUNT(ID) > 1) S ON S.ID=M.ID
WHERE M.STATUS = 'Current'
```

Answer (score 0):

All of your sample data have exactly one row with `'Current'`.  So, the simplest solution appears to be:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.status = 'Current';
```